# Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded, Google Play Services. Freeze when launching

Tags: java, android, eclipse, macos, google-play-services

I have encountered this problem after trying to implement Google Play Services in my application.

I figured I did not give enough "power" to eclipse so I changed my eclipse.ini file. However it does not help even though I increase the value.

My eclipse.ini:

```
-startup

../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar

--launcher.library

../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212

-product

org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product

--launcher.defaultAction

openFile

-showsplash

org.eclipse.platform

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize

4096m

--launcher.defaultAction

openFile

--launcher.appendVmargs

-vmargs

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6

-XstartOnFirstThread

-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts

-Xms4096m

-Xmx8192m

-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns

-XstartOnFirstThread

-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

I have tried to reinstall my sdk, changed my BuildPath and even reinstalled Eclipse, but nothing helps. When I try to run my project Eclipse freezes.

Help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEM FINALLY SOLVED**
My Mac osx computer had Eclipse installed in two places, one in applications (Where I canged the .ini) and one in Downloads, which I had not touched.

... osx, this took some hours.